# Improve Core Data performance with sectionIndexTitlesForTableView

Tags: core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm working with an extremely large data set with Core Data. Currently I have my main managedObjectContext and in the background I populate data from a network source on a child managedObjectContext with it's parent context set to my main.

The problem I'm running into is as I save on the background context and then save on my main context the UI is slow and it seems to be because it's having to load all my NSManageObject objects into memory in order to calculate the sectionIndexTitlesForTableView.

Is there a way that I can correctly count the sectionIndexTitles but only load a few NSManagedObjects into memory?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you precalculate the values? E.g. create an extra db table that has the values for sectionIndexTitlesForTableView?

Comment: That I can do but lets say I have section titles A-Z but I only have A-E values loaded. Would jumping to Z just display a blank section?

Comment: is this for a dictionary? How many words?

Comment: It's a map type thing. Each section represent places that start with that name. Currently I'm working with around 17,000 places. Which is why I'd only like to load a few in memory to display but still be able to jump correctly.

Comment: Take the longest place name, say 30 characters. Create a text file of the place names each of fixed length according to the maximum. Map your table view to a pointer within that file. So for example entry at index row 3 would be the place name in the file starting at 3 * 30 characters. You will need to maintain a table somewhere of initial place names so that you can do the table index. This approach will give you incredible performance. I used exactly this technique for a dictionary of 170K words. Core Data delivers a possibly unacceptable lag when loading such a large data set.

Comment: Are you suggesting moving away from CoreData all together for this large dataset?

Comment: Typically in projects we've used a combination of both. CoreData for queries, etc. Flat files for performance. I'd never have guessed it myself that a flat file performs better but I've been proven wrong on one project at least.

Comment: Thanks for all your input Max. Gives me something to go after.

Comment: No worries. I'll write up a couple of the options as an answer